# How to append "%" to a string in EL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I would like to construct a string with `"%"` in it in a `<c:set>` tag.

Here it goes:

```
<c:set var="test" value="${somethingA + '%' }" />
```

But this always give me a number format exception.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "%"
```

So how do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who wonder the same.

```
<c:set var="test" value="${somethingA }%" />
```

If there are more to come after the `%`, simply do

```
<c:set var="test" value="${somethingA }%${somethingElse }" />
```